# Flex Box Model Spec

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using the flex box model in my css for the first time. Everything renders well in Chrome & Safari but Firefox is just a big mess, and I haven't gotten to a PC yet to test in IE. Am I using the correct properties for the flex box model? Please see my style sheet at http://www.emilydiane.net/ebbg/styles.css

Thanks :)

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't work in IE at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using old flexbox syntax.

`display: box;` is an old 2009-ish syntax.

Check out the spec: [w3.org flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox) and get familiar with the new syntax.